# "rake db:seed" no method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seeding

when I try and run the "rake db:seed" command the rails console outputs "NoMethodError: undefined method `db' for #" not quite sure what going on. I'm using netbeans to build my rails project which is using the built-in JRuby 1.2 would that have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

You should run this command not from a rails console, but from your OS console, like bash or zsh.